# ImageView over a fragment not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview

I have a fragment (a SupportMapFragment, actually) and I want to put an ImageView, over it, in a corner of the map, but not covering all the map fragment, just a little. My layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imagenTick"
    android:background="@color/componente_boton_base_seleccionar_defecto"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tick"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="ImagenTick"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mapfragment"/>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment" />
```

Right now, the ImageView is behind the mapFragment, and it is not visible. I want it to be visible, but can't find a way to tell Android Studio i want it over the map to make it visible, not behind.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the order. Put first your Fragment and then your ImageView. When using RelativeLayout, the last element should be on top.

Comment: That worked. If you put it in an answer, I will upvote you. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the order. Put first your Fragment and then your ImageView. When using RelativeLayout, the last element should be on top.